# How to use external source data in React-Native collapsible/accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native collapsible/accordion on my project. I found an example of it which is here below

```
import React, {` Component } from 'react-native';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

const SECTIONS = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
  }
];

class AccordionView extends Component {
  _renderHeader(section) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{section.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderContent(section) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>{section.content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Accordion
        sections={SECTIONS}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        renderContent={this._renderContent}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I have stored my data in `state` like that

```
state = { orders: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/c6ccf4e2-3871-11e7-ae4c-bb26ea80a2f8')
      .then(response => this.setState({ orders: response.data }));
  }
```

So my question is how I can use my data (`orders`) instead of `SECTIONS` on the example code above. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go, just replace SECTIONS with this.state.orders

```
    render() {
      return (
        <Accordion
          sections={this.state.orders}
          renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
          renderContent={this._renderContent}
        />
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to react-native. That really helps